# Can't make Xubuntu persistent live USB using Rufus

Tags: system-installation, xubuntu, live-usb, rufus

I'm trying to fully install Xubuntu on a 16 GB USB (with persistence). After several atempts, I still can't boot on it.

The ISO was burnt onto the USB using the last version of Rufus with the persistence enabled. After booting from the USB, my screen shows:

```
[        7.990790] Couldn't get size: 0x800000000000000e

(initramfs) stdin: Invalid argument  
stdin: Invalid argument  
mount: mounting /cow on /root failed: Invalid argument
```

What am I missing? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Persistent partitions are only working with Rufus using Ubuntu 19.10 and later, I understand.

Comment: You can post your image it just won't be visible until someone edits your question to make it visible. That usually happens with in 24 hours.

Comment: Related: [How is it easier to make a persistent live drive with Ubuntu 19.10?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1181854/37165), which mentioned using Rufus as well as other tools.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Persistent partitions are only working with latest Rufus using Ubuntu 19.10 and later**.

Rufus 3.8 worked great for me using the daily release of Eoan Ermine.

Ubuntu 19.10 is now in Beta and will be released on October 17.

Comment: +1. I'm looking forward to 20.04 next spring. I might make the switch from 16.04 then.

Comment: Note: The reason persistent partitions are not working with Ubuntu 19.04 or earlier is because of this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/casper/+bug/1489855, that has only been fixed in 19.10.

Comment: @Akeo: Is it a syslinux thing? Grub Live installers like mkusb and looped ISOs work with 14.04 to 19.04 and persistent partitions. Syslinux Live installers like UNetbootin, Universal and Rufus did not.

Comment: No, it's a generic bug. You will run into it (on UEFI systems, but if you know your way around Syslinux you can also show it on BIOS) if you simply create a FAT32 partition, copy all the content from a pre 19.10 ISO onto it, then create a second persistent partition after the FAT32 one, format it to `ext2`/`ext3`/`ext4` with label `casper-rw` and add the `persistent` kernel option to the `boot/grub/grub.cfg`. This very generic (and relatively easy) method of enabling persistence should always have worked, but didn't until 19.10, due to the rather unfortunate bug above... No Syslinux required.

Comment: Basically, the Ubuntu scripts that are supposed to detect and mount a persistent partition have been broken for years and I explained precisely how that happens in the comment I left for the bug report here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/casper/+bug/1489855/comments/26. Depending on whether you are working with a persistent file or an external partition, the bug will not trigger, but as soon as you use the fairly standard configuration I highlighted above, you will run into it, which makes it all the more puzzling why more people haven't reported that they were impaired by this.

Comment: But grub2 persistent OS, like mkusb or booted ISO files work fine with persistent partitions?